# GetText using li tag returns blank in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

**HTML**

```
<div class="WIS wd-popup wdappchrome-ad" data-popup-version="2" data-automation-id="searchInputAutocompletePopup" data-automation-activepopup="true" style="padding: 7px 0px; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 50; top: 92px; left: 65px;">
    <div class="WFS wd-popup-content wdappchrome-ae" style="max-height: 195px; max-width: 1282px;">
        <ul class="wdappchrome-ah" aria-setsize="3">
            <li class="wdappchrome-ai" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResult" tabindex="0" aria-posinset="1"><span data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultFullText"><span style="font-weight:500"><span style="font-weight:400" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken">Build</span> <span style="font-weight:400" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken">Your</span>-<span style="font-weight:400" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken">Resume</span> <span style="font-weight:400" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken">first</span> Plan</span>
                </span><span class="wdappchrome-aj" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultType"> - Feature</span></li>

           <li class="wdappchrome-ai" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResult" tabindex="0" aria-posinset="2"><span data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultFullText"><span style="font-weight:500"><span style="font-weight:400" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken">Build</span> <span style="font-weight:400" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken">Your</span>-<span style="font-weight:400" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken">Resume</span> <span style="font-weight:400" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken">Second</span> Plan Configurable Category</span>
                </span><span class="wdappchrome-aj" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultType"> - Feature</span></li>

            <li class="wdappchrome-ai" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResult" tabindex="0" aria-posinset="3"><span data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultFullText"><span style="font-weight:500"><span style="font-weight:400" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken">Build</span> <span style="font-weight:400" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken">Your</span>-<span style="font-weight:400" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken">Resume</span> <span style="font-weight:400" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultToken">Third</span> Plan Schedule</span>
                </span><span class="wdappchrome-aj" data-automation-id="searchInputAutoCompleteResultType"> - Feature</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div role="presentation" class="WMS wd-popup-anchor WPS WPR"></div>
</div>
```

**I tried to select option from auto populate result**

```
 try {
 WebElement autoOptions =driver.findElement(By.className("wdappchrome-ah"));


                List<WebElement> optionsToSelect = autoOptions.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

                System.out.println("TExt : " + optionsToSelect.get(0).getText());
                System.out.println(optionsToSelect.get(1).getText());
                System.out.println(optionsToSelect.get(2).getText());

                for (WebElement option : optionsToSelect) {
                    if (option.getText().equals(textToSelect)) {
                        System.out.println("Trying to select: " + textToSelect);
                        option.click();
                        break;
                    }
                }

            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            }}
```

**Steps to Automate**

1. Enter text to Search. i.e `Build your own resume`
2. Website populates auto complete result based on search text
3. I have added html code of how it display result after search
4. I want to select particular result based on text.

**Issue I am facing**

I am getting correct number of `li` using my above code but when I do `GETTEXT`it returns me blank. Here result comes with li and then whole search word is divided using `span` and that's what I unable to manage and get whole text.

Comment: Are you expecting `optionsToSelect` to be a list containing something like `[Build, your,  own, resume]`? And if `textToSelect` is `own`, click on it when the loop finds it?

Comment: @HaC - Yes correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Selenium in Java but the result you are getting seems logical because you are trying to extract text from parent element instead of the element itself.

**Update:** in your HTML the spans of each Li contain the text 3 times distributed along spans, you just need to get text from first span.

Try something like:

```
            String textToSelect;
            List<WebElement> optionsToSelect = autoOptions.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

            for (WebElement option : optionsToSelect) {
                textToSelect="";
                List<WebElement> textPerLi= option .findElements(By.tagName("span"));

                  textToSelect=textToSelect+textPerLi.get(0).getText();

                if ("Text you want to match with".equals(textToSelect)) {
                    System.out.println("Trying to select: " + textToSelect);
                    option.click();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your given code is storing same text multiple times in variable. i.e in loop I am getting text like  `textToSelect = Build your own resume plan - featureBuild your own resume plan - featureBuild your own resume plan - feature `.

Comment: you want to get "Build your own resume plan" for example, right? if the updated code did not work, can you please paste full HTML ?

Comment: Yes Correct. Still I have same issue.

Comment: then seems like all the spans are inside one li, post the full HTML please

Comment: I have updated html , Please see 3 `li` appear with span as auto complete result texts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158393/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-yahya-hussein).

Answer (score 0):

To select particular result based on text you can use the following code block:

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='wdappchrome-ah']/li//span[@data-automation-id='searchAutoCompleteResultToken']"));
for (WebElement my_option:options)
{
    String innerhtml = my_option.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    if(innerhtml.contentEquals("textToSelect"))
    {
        my_option.click();
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Option chosen is : "+innerhtml);    
}
```

Comment: Variable `innerhtml` returns me only `- Feature`

Comment: Can you update the question formatting the `HTML` just like the actual `HTML`?

Comment: Check out the updated Answer. Update me the Status please.

Comment: Not success yet, Let me update with more part of html in question.

Comment: I have updated html , Please see 3 `li` appear with span as auto complete result texts.